# Swift: Deleting Rows in TableView Sections in Realm vs CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, realm

I am trying to build the same data persistance functionality in two apps that are the same. 
But one is with CoreData and the other with Realm.

In my Realm driven app the code works just fine and the app works as it should for deleting the rows both in the tableview and in the database table.

But the application with CoreData doesn't work as expected.
It consists of a TableView. The number of sections are represented by the number of semester objects saved in the Semester Entity Table. 
The rows of each section are represented by the subject objects, that are in relation with the semester object. 
When I try to delete a row in a section, the app crashes with:

> [error] error: NSFetchedResultsController: no object at index 4 in
>   section at index 0 CoreData: error: NSFetchedResultsController: no
>   object at index 4 in section at index 0 2020-03-08
>   15:33:04.936347+0100 StudyOverview[48246:4762080] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'no
>   object at index 4 in section at index 0'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Here is the code responsible for the RealmApp to delete the rows:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
        let allSemester = realm.objects(Semester.self)
        let subjects = allSemester[indexPath.section].subjectsOfSemester
        try! realm.write{
            realm.delete(subjects[indexPath.row])
        }
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the app with CoreData:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
            let semesterArray = frc.fetchedObjects
            let semester = semesterArray?[indexPath.section]
            let subjectList = semester?.subjectRelation?.allObjects as! [Subject]
            context?.delete(subjectList[indexPath.row])
            semesterTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Here is the function in which I defined the FetchedResultsController (frc):

```
func useFRC(){
    let semesterRequest:NSFetchRequest<Semester> = Semester.fetchRequest()
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "semester", ascending: true)
    semesterRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: semesterRequest, managedObjectContext: context!, sectionNameKeyPath: #keyPath(Semester.semester), cacheName: nil)

    do{
        try frc.performFetch()
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }

    semesterTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Can someone explain me, what I have to do different with CoreData to get the same result as with Realm?
Below is also a picture of my Entities and their Relationship, if this can help.

[image]

Comment: Stating *doesn't work as expected.* is vague. Questions need to include the intended behavior and a brief explanation of what the code is doing. Additionally fetching the objects from Realm is clear `let allSemester = realm.objects(Semester.self)` but we don't know what this `frc.fetchedObjects` does. Why are you not getting a child array from this `semesterArray?[indexPath.section]` and also what `semester?.subjectRelation` subjectRelation is. Please don't make us guess! Review the following guide on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Jay Thank you for your feedback, I tried to edit the question. I also had the wrong screenshot of the diagram uploaded accidentally, which looks similar. Hope it is better now. 
I also don't understand quiet well, what you mean with the child array. My goal was to get all the semester objects, then all the subject objects that are related to the the corresponding semesters and delete the subject/entry at the chose indexPath.row. 
At least this way I could fetch the subjects and make them visible in my tableview at the correct section. Thought it might also work for deleting

Comment: If you are using `FetchedResultsController` implement its delegate methods. Then delete the items in the context and save the context. The controller does the rest and updates the UI.

Comment: When I mentioned childArray, I was referring to this *semester?.subjectRelation?.allObjects* - we don't know what subjectRelation is but since you're referencing `.allObjects`, I assumed it was an array of objects

Comment: Oh.. Is this `semesterTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath]` supposed to be `indexPath.row`?

Comment: @vadian I tried with the delegate, but unfortunately it won't work. At least the app didn't crash. 
I uncommented the line "semesterTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)" , saved the context and reload the tableview. The App won't crash this way but, an empty tableviewcell remains, until the app gets restartet.
So the problem lies within the deleting function of the row afterwards.

Comment: If you use the delegate methods you **must not** call `deleteRows` nor `reloadData`. And make sure that the delegate method to manage the sections is implemented, too. And you have to set the delegate in `useFRC`

Comment: @Jay the .allObjects fetch all the corresponding Subjects as an array of Subjects. And .subjectRelation refers to the One-To-Many Relationship of the Semester Entity with the Subject Entity.
Regarding the indexPath question, I hoped that it would delete the row. But I don't know how I have to adjust that part, since this is the function that makes my app crash

Comment: The error is pretty clear - you're trying to delete an object from your tableView that doesn't exist - there is no object in section 0, index 4, which is called from this code `.deleteRows(at: [indexPath]`. IndexPath is 4 which is not what you want - you want it to be the index of the row in that section your trying to delete.